# How to measure the average speed of my web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I have written a REST web service. I want to get some performance statistics for client reference. What is the best way to measure the performance of my service ? Should I run a timer from the client making the request or the time it takes the server once a request is received.

How can effectively measure the speed of my web service ?

**Note****

I'm aware that the answers to this question borders on being opinion, however I think that there is a consensus approved approach for getting these stats.

Comment: under load or with no load... that is the question...  pretty much any load testing tool should give you the metrics you are looking for.  for a basic test you could make the requests from a web browser and use fiddler to grab the statistics of how long it took.

Comment: http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmark it. Apache provides the [`ab`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench) tool, which does this for you.

It will show you how many requests the server can handle per second. You can even fine-tune your settings, since it has a lot of options (like concurrency, the way of connecting, etc).

Of course, there are a lot of [other benchmark tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking)

Comment: I should have mentioned I am running on windows server 2008.

Comment: That's not relevant - it's available for Windows as well.